# SVG - Text with background color and rounded borders

Tags: svg

Is it possible to make such a thing with pure SVG?

[image]

Without Javascript, fixed sizes or html.

I tried to use a rect element but this is not a flexible solution.

I tried to use a filter but this is a solution without rounded corners.

Comment: You can draw a rect with rounded corners like this: `<rect x ="10" y ="120" height ="100" width ="100" rx ="10" ry ="10" />` you can draw the text using the text element.

Comment: This is a solution with fixed width.

Comment: Your svg element can take whatever width you need

Comment: I need width depended on the text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with a filter in two alternative ways:

1. Do a flood, blur it, then clip the low opacities, then dial up the remaining opacity to full
2. Smuggle in a rounded corner rect via feImage and use relative sizing to stretch it

In both cases padding is relative so if your text is too long, the rounded corners will overflow the filter area. Unlike CSS, you can't combine relative and absolute sizings in SVG (well SVG 1.1 at least). So this is as good as you get.

Since you're really looking for HTML text behavior but you want it in SVG, you might want to consider using a foreignObject and embedding HTML text that way.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
<defs>
  <filter id="rounded-corners" x="-5%" width="110%" y="0%" height="100%">
<feFlood flood-color="#FFAA55"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="table"tableValues="0 0 0 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>

<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncA type="table"tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
   <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  
   <filter id="rounded-corners-2" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<feImage preserveAspectRatio="none" width="110%" height="110%" x="-5%" y="0%"  xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 400 40' height='40' width='400'%3E%3Crect fill='red' x='0' y='0' rx='10' ry='10' width='400' height='40'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
   <feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter> 
  
  
  </defs>

  
  <text filter="url(#rounded-corners)" x="20" y="40" style="font-size:30">Blur & opacity filter</text>
  
  <text filter="url(#rounded-corners)" x="20" y="80" style="font-size:30"> But the x padding is relative and overflows with long text</text>
  
<text filter="url(#rounded-corners-2)" x="20" y="140" style="font-size:30">feImage and a rect filter</text>
  
<text filter="url(#rounded-corners-2)" x="20" y="180" style="font-size:30">But you still can't get away from relative padding</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: The idea of using filters is very interesting(+). Unfortunately the filter `filter id =" rounded-corners-2 "` does not work in `Firefox`

Comment: Ah - Firefox requires some extra escaping in the data URI - fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much simpler option (if you don't need to use stroke for something else): giving the text element a massive stroke width, using the paint order attribute to specify that it be drawn behind the fill, and then using css clip path to apply a rounded inset clip to the text element. Adjust the negative values of the inset clip to adjust padding appropriately.  (You may have to scroll the code snippet window down to see it)

```css
svg text {
  clip-path: inset(-5px -5px -5px -5px round 10px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xml:space="preserve"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      style="fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-miterlimit:2"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <text style="paint-order:stroke fill"
         stroke="salmon"
         stroke-width="50"
         x="50%" y="50%"
         dominant-baseline="middle"
         text-anchor="middle"
         fill="black">
      hello 
   </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This shows 'clipping' with single characters.

Which can be prevented by adding `<tspan dx="-1.3" fill="salmon">|</tspan>` before 'hello' and changing clip-path to `inset(-5px -5px -5px -2.4px round 10px)`.

(With the bar character being arbitrary.)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, but it 's actually way easier to work with a foreignObject.