# What technology has been used to generate this dynamic text on SVG and convert them to paths while auto adjusting the width?

Tags: svg, canvas, text, dynamic, width

he following banner is an example of what i want:
https://top.gg/api/widget/535064930727100427.svg
https://top.gg/api/widget/698275428976164945.svg

It's automatically generated and contains dynamic text which causes the "background color" to automatically adjust its size to it as well as have a border radius.

The text and shapes are all paths when I look at the source.

I would like to know how this has been accomplished as SVG itself does not support a dynamic border radius and background color by default.

Somewhere in the SVG source of the links above it shows`id="surface19"` and I did some research to see what piece of software or library provides such ID's. The text also seems to automatically be converted to paths, so it's not a hand-written SVG that gets modified programmatically from what it seems.

I did a lot of research before asking this question.

Comment: The background is probably a rect whose width and height adjusts based on the length of the svg text text content. But how it’s determining the length of of text content is unknown to me. Also why would they use an svg for this? Seems unnecessarily difficult to do so when you could use other HTML objects.

Comment: If you actually want to ask how to do it then there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172331/svg-text-with-background-color-and-rounded-borders)

Comment: @Robert Longson The solution you've provided is not the answer to my question unfortunately. That solution uses SVG's filter option and does not properly adjust to the text underneath it. When the text is too wide, the "border-radius" gets out of shape. Also it doesn't seem to be a good practice solution to me.

The links that I've posted must've been generated with something, and I'm just not sure what. It's not a handwritten SVG.

Comment: It would be better if you stated all your requirements and what you've done so far to solve the problem.